# How to fix Console Writing the name of the Class?

Tags: c#, indexer

I am new to C# and I am struggling with this since hours and would appreciate your help.

I want to create a Polygon and Write down each position of the points.

Currently I have this:
-Class Point

```
class Point
{
    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Point(int x2, int y2)
    {
        x = x2;
        y = y2;
    }
}
```

-Class Polygon

```
class Polygon
{
    private Point[] Points;

    public Polygon(params Point[] a)
    {
        Points = new Point[a.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            Points[i] = a[i];
        }
    }

    public Point this[int index]
    {
        get { return Points[index]; }
        set { Points[index] = value;}
    }
}
```

Now I have this in my main:

```
        Polygon First= new Polygon(new Point(7,4), new Point(4,1), new Point(2, 1));

        First[0] = new Point(3, 4);

        Console.WriteLine("points of polygon ");
        for (int i = 0; i < First.PointCounter; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(First[i]);
        }
```

But now instead of seeing each position of the Point after "points of polygon" I see this in my Console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENSHI.jpg

How it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFOSs.jpg

How it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFOSs.jpg

Comment: One thing you need to know: `override string ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an override of `ToString` so that your `Point` class has the expected output when converted to string. An output like `"x:3   y:4"`.

```
class Point
{
    public int x { get; private set; }
    public int y { get; private set; }

    public Point(int x2, int y2)
    {
        x = x2;
        y = y2;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"x:{x,-3} y:{y,-3}";
    }
}
```

As it is now, it is a good candidate for becoming a `struct` instead of `class`.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help sir. It worked!.

Comment: You are welcome my friend! I would appreciate a thumbs up. :-)

Comment: @MickyD you are right. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

C# is not "interpreted" like other languages, so the `Console.WriteLine` method won't guess what you're trying to have printed.

To give the result you're looking for, with your current code, you would have to provide public properties to your `Point` class:

```
public int X { get { return x;} set{ x = value;} }
public int Y { get { return y;} set{ y = value;} }
```

After which you could now access those properties in your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < First.PointCounter; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"x:{First[i].X}    y:{First[i].Y}");
}
```

Comment: Provide the solution with .ToString() override as well that seems pretty good as well for this case.

Comment: @CoderofCode I'm personally not all that keen on overriding the `.ToString()` method. But if you would like to add it in here, do please go ahead.

Comment: `ToString()` has legitimate use cases.

Comment: @MickyD Absolutely. I'm just not keen on giving that as an answer to someone who's new to the language, as misuse of it can lead to pretty difficult debugging, from exp.
But either way, Theodor Zoulias's solution works.

Comment: _"new to the language"_ - Ah yes excellent point.  By giving the properties makes it more obvious what is happening.  +1 good sir